# Как обойти блокировку для подключения по TCP?

Tags: c#, proxy, tcp, vpn, блокировки

Я хочу сделать приложение по распознаванию речи используя `SpeechKit Cloud API Yandex`, но моей стране заблокировали ип, сервисы Яндекса.

Первое, что нужно сделать:

> ***Подключение к серверу распознавания:*** Клиентское приложение подключается к серверу SpeechKit Cloud по протоколу TCP, через 80 порт сервера (для обращения по HTTP) или 443
>   порт (для обращения по HTTPS). Рекомендуется подключаться через 443
>   порт, так как в этом случае используется защищенное HTTP соединение.

`"asr.yandex.net"` - (адрес к которому нужно подключиться) заблокирован. Как решить эту проблему? Использовать proxy, vpn?

Есть ли готовые классы, которые позволят создать TCP подключения в C# и обойти блокировку каким-то образом?

*К сожалению не подходит вариант включить vpn на всем компьютере, то есть пустить весь трафик через vpn. Требуется сделать так, чтобы только приложение работало через vpn/proxy.*

Comment: Вы сами подключаетесь к серверу, или это делает 3rd party код?

Comment: @Zergatul сам хочу подключиться. Нужно написать на c# для себя подключение. [Внизу есть простой пример на Python](https://tech.yandex.ru/speechkit/cloud/doc/guide/concepts/speechkit-cloud-asr-protobuf-docpage/#steps__connectionrequest) Нужно также только на C#. Но не могу даже начать начать, ибо мало в этом смыслю и еще адреса яндекса заблокированы. Чтобы начать ковырять api нужно как-то для начала подключиться..

Comment: Вам будет достаточно создание `TcpClient`, который работает через прокси?

Comment: @Zergatul думаю, да. В c#  есть класс `Socket`, но никак не могу понять как пустить через прокси трафик. Возможно данный класс на это не способен.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать `TcpClient` работающий через прокси.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы создать `TcpClient` работающий через прокси, можете посмотреть мою библиотеку: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/tree/master/Zergatul/Network/Proxy

Есть Socks4, Socks5, Http tunnel proxy (HttpProxy класс)

Использовать так:

```
var proxy = new HttpProxy("ваш прокси", port);
TcpClient client = proxy.CreateConnection("asr.yandex.net", 80);

// дальше работаете с client как с обычным TcpClient
```

Выполнить простейший http запрос можно так:

```
string request =
    "GET / HTTP/1.0" + Environment.NewLine +
    "Host: " + host + Environment.NewLine +
    Environment.NewLine;
client.GetStream().Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request));

var sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: `443 порт (для обращения по HTTPS)` ведь не просто так ?

Comment: Автор указал, что можно и по http и по https

Comment: +++ от меня библиотеку смотрел ранее VladD скидывал ссылку.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать и учиться.

Comment: @Zergatul , `proxy.CreateConnection("asr.yandex.net", 80);` не могу выполнить, постоянно при подключении возникает ошибка: `400 bad requst`. Можно пример расширить, как правильно сделать `Get запрос` при помощи  `HttpProxy` и `TcpClient`?

Comment: @XXX скорее всего вы подключаетесь к чистому http прокси, который может выполнять только http запросы, и ничего больше. Мой класс ожидает https-прокси ("народное" название), такой вид прокси может работать с любым tcp протоколом, включая https.

Comment: @XXX я добавил пример как сделать простой запрос

Comment: @Zergatul, Вы правы! Я не правильное прокси выбрал. Спасибо.